# I'm Getting WordPress Comment Spam That's Bypassing my Comment Form. How Can I Combat This?

Tags: php, wordpress

All posts on my blog have open comments, no matter the age of the article. The comment form requires a name, URL, and comment in order to be submitted. I get notified of each comment via email through WordPress and all comments are held for moderation before approval.

Lately I'm getting the same comment spam being submitted as comments but there are a few anomalies:

- Each comment has more or less the same text. I've added that text as restricted text in my WordPress Discussion settings, but it still bypasses that filter.
- Each comment has no email address submitted. Somehow they're bypassing the email field by (I'm assuming) targeting comments.php directly.
- Each comment has a different IP address, so I can't even block by IP in .htaccess, since it's always new.

Any idea how this can be combated? I'm using an anti-spam plugin that I pay for but I don't see a way for it to combat this specific problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bizarre thing about this problem is that these were not "comments" being posted that were getting through the spam filter, they were "trackbacks" and "pingbacks". Usually tracks/pings are identified as such, but for some reason these were different. They looked like comments.

I don't need to be notified about trackbacks so I used the WordPress dashboard to disable all trackbacks/pingbacks on older posts. You can do this by doing the following:

- Choose Posts, All Posts
- Click "Screen Options" at the top to select how many posts to display in the list (e.g. you can display up to 999)
- Select all posts
- Change the "Bulk Actions" dropdown to "edit"
- Click "apply"
- From the new options that appear, click the dropdown next to "Pings" and select "Do not allow".
- Click "Update"

I'll monitor to see if the trackback comments are continuing to get through, but I believe this should fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

These two plugins could help you

https://akismet.com/wordpress/
https://www.wordfence.com/
Also try using cloudflare to mitigate bot traffic

Comment: Thanks. I already have the free version of WordFence installed but maybe I'll check and see if there's some feature that can prevent this.